# Validating a string date against a strftime format

Tags: javascript, node.js, strftime

I would like to validate, in node.js, if a date string matches a [strftime](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strftime.html) format (preferrably the [Ruby's version](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime)).
E.g.: Format is `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%Z`, then `1912-02-12T08:15:03.131Z` would be a valid value and `1912-02-12` would be invalid.
[d3-time-format](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format) and [strftime](https://github.com/samsonjs/strftime) use the desirable set of tokens, but they are only converters. [luxon](https://github.com/moment/luxon) or [Moment.js](https://github.com/moment/moment) have a mean to validate the format, but the tokens are different and the format would have to be converted (here is a table of tokens for [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/parsing.html#table-of-tokens) and here for [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)). Is there a way to do it in any simpler way?

Comment: Is https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format#locale_parse not enough …?

Comment: @04FS of course it is enough. I have no idea how I missed that. Feel kinda dumb now, haha. Thank you.

Comment: @RobG this works only for the `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%Z` pattern though. If I wanted to validate the date against, e.g. `%Y-%m-%d`, then this would not help.

Comment: Sure, didn't get that from the OP. :-o